# Why this "gcc.exe: error: array: No such file or directory" message appeared whenever I run mycode on VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[This message appeared whenever I run my code on VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mivr.png)

Comment: File names can't contain spaces, simple as that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.